# Practice for tracking objects created in C++?

Tags: c++

A common technique for keeping track of the number of objects in a Java program is that each appearance of the keyword `new` indicates a new object has been created.

However, C++ is much more flexible in object creation; we can have an explicit constructor, implicit constructor, copy initialization, returning an object by value in a method, `new` keyword, and so on.

For C++ developers, what common techniques do you use to keep a mental count of the number of objects created (as oppose to being passed around by reference, pointer, etc)?

<sub>I am not sure if this question belongs on Stack Overflow ore is more suited for another Stack Exchange site. Please feel free to suggest a migration.</sub>

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting

Comment: Depends. What do you want to do with it? Which object type and what allocation-type do you want to count? Do you need a statically proven upper bound or the current count?

Comment: I don't think OP is interested into actual techniques for counting live objects, but for code reading technique that helps him. But I don't know if this makes the question any more suitable for SO.

Comment: Perhaps I was a little unclear in the original question, @pmr is spot on. I am interested in quick tips or tricks used by more experienced C++ developers to improve my code reading skills (which explains the Java example, suggested to me by another developer), rather than a programmatic or formal method of object counting.

Comment: If you downvoted the question, please explain why.

Answer (score 0):

This question hasn't received much attention, but a good code reading technique I have found is that a raw class name in the source file *generally* indicates a new object has been created.

For example, if I am calling the function

`Matrix multiply(Matrix a, Matrix b);`

indicates we have three new objects being created, the two parameters `Matrix a` and `Matrix b` are copied to the function stack frame, and what ever `Matrix` is returned from `multiply` is copied back to the caller's frame (assuming no return-value optimization or move semantics).

One way I have found this helpful is to avoid using `Java` style constructors, which may be costly for certain compilers. For example,

`Matrix a = Matrix(4,5)`

Is likely creating a temporary, unnamed matrix and then using the copy-constructor to initialize the named `Matrix`.